# Check if Modal is rendered with conditional props in jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, modal-dialog, enzyme

I am using react and jest enzyme to test the components.I have a component which conditionally renders a modal with an onClick. This onClick also contains a param. I am not able to check in test file if the modal renders or not.

The Component code is

```
handleModal = (name) => {
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return{
     ['show_'+ name]: !prevState['show_'+ name]
  }
  })}
  
 return (Object.keys(obj).map((name, index) => {
    return (
        {
          (name === 'MODAL1'|| name === 'MODAL2' ) ? 
          (<div >
            <a onClick={() => {this.handleModal(name)}}  }>{obj[name]}</a>
            { this.state['show_'+ name] && (
              <Modal show={this.state['show_'+ name]} onClose={() => {this.handleModal(name)}} className="modal">
               
              ....
              </Modal>
            )}
          </div>)
          : <td>{obj[name]}</td>
        }
```

The jest function is

```
it('checkModal', () => {
 const renderedModule = mount(<Component {...props}/>); 
 renderedModule.instance().state.show_MODAL1 = true;
 expect(renderedModule.find('.modal').prop('show')).toBe(true);
 });
```

I am learning react and I want to increase code coverage. The line uncovered is

```
<a onClick={() => {this.handleModal(name)}}  }>{obj[name]}</a>
            { this.state['show_'+ name] && (
              <Modal show={this.state['show_'+ name]} onClose={() => {this.handleModal(name)}} className="modal">
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your `.at(index)` (enzyme's `find()` returns a collection of nodes:

```
expect(renderedModule.find('.modal').at(0).prop('show')).toBe(true);
```

or

```
expect(renderedModule.find(Modal).at(0).prop('show')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: It gives me this "Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead" everytime I use find. I think the test code doesn't covers the modal.